# Calculating norms of prime ideal by hand

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, algebraic-number-theory

Let $K=\mathbb{Q}(a)$ with $a^3+10a+1=0$. Note that $\mathfrak{p}=(2,1+a)$ is a prime ideal. In my course notes, it says that $N\mathfrak{p}=2$, where $N I:= (\mathcal{O}_K:I)$ for any ideal $I$ of $\mathcal{O}_K=\mathbb{Z}[a]$, the ring of integers over $K$. My question is, how to go about calculating $N \mathfrak{p}$ without using a computer? Is there a systematic way? In other words, I don't know how to obtain the answer of 2 by hand. Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1):

Note that $\Bbb Z[a] \cong \Bbb Z[X]/(X^3 + 10X + 1)$. Thus, the following holds;

\begin{align}
\Bbb Z[a]/(2, 1+a) &\cong \Bbb Z[X]/(2, 1 + X, X^3 + 10X + 1)\\
&\cong \Bbb F_2[X]/(1+ X, X^3 + 1)\\
&\cong \Bbb F_2[X]/(1 + X)\\
&\cong \Bbb F_2.
\end{align}

Now we have that $(\mathcal{O}_K:\mathfrak{p}) = 2.$

Comment: Am I right to say that if $p$ is prime, and $g$ is an irreducible factor of $f$ modulo $p$, $f$ being the minimal polynomial over $\mathbb{Q}$ of the extension, then $N(p,g(a))=p^{\text{deg} g}$?